# retrieve the label value from a TileList (Flash CS5 AS3)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, label, trace, tilelist

I have a TileList, that i loaded with a PHP script that gives back an dinamically generated xml so i can load the TileList with the images and labels it needs.

Now, i want to click on an item of the TileList an retrieve its Label so i can send it to another PHP script that uses the string of the Label to do a search query so i can load latitud and longitude to a map to where that item is located.

i have been trying to trace it, but its a no go.

```
var path:String = "http://localhost/entretenimiento.php";
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest(path));       

function onLoadComplete(e:Event):void {
    System.disposeXML(xmlData);
    var xmlData:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
    //trace(xmlData);

    for (var i:int=0; i<xmlData.e_nombre.length(); i++)
    {
        myTileList.addItem({label:xmlData.e_nombre[i], source:xmlData.e_imagen[i]});
        //trace(xmlData.e_nombre[i]);
    }

    var display;
    myTileList.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, listListener);
    myTileList.selectedIndex = 0;

    function listListener(event:Event):void {
    display.source = myTileList.selectedItem.label;
    trace(display.source);
    trace("working");

    }

}
```

I need help, i dont know how to retrieve the label from item clicked on the TileList.

Im using Flash CS5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well...

this was simple, after a nap i just sat down and tried this and it gave me what i wanted.

```
var path:String = "http://localhost/entretenimiento.php";
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest(path));       

function onLoadComplete(e:Event):void {
  System.disposeXML(xmlData);
  var xmlData:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
  //trace(xmlData);

  for (var i:int=0; i<xmlData.e_nombre.length(); i++)
  {
      myTileList.addItem({label:xmlData.e_nombre[i], source:xmlData.e_imagen[i]});
      //trace(xmlData.e_nombre[i]);
  }

  myTileList.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, listListener);
  myTileList.selectedIndex = 0;

  function listListener(event:Event):void {

  trace(myTileList.selectedItem.label);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// this should live somewhere in your code:
var path:String = "http://localhost/entretenimiento.php";
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
    xmlLoader.load( new URLRequest( path ));

private function onComplete(e:Event):void
{
    // XML works just fine as a data provider, you don't need the loop.
    myTileList.dataProvider = new DataProvider(new XML(e.target.data));
    // You can assign which properties of the xml the list uses.
    myTileList.sourceField = "e_imagen";
    myTileList.labelField = "e_nombre"; 
    // I'm assuming that the goal is to have the user select an item, 
    //     so we'll register to listen for a click.
    myTileList.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, listListener );
}

private function listListener(e:Event):void
{
    /* 
    Because we're listening for a click, and the listener is registered to the list
    make sure that what we've clicked is an item (a CellRenderer) and not the
    background or something.
    */

    if ( getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(e.target)) == CellRenderer )
    {
        // You can call your other web service from here.
        // The "target" is a CellRenderer, and its data is an XML node.
        trace(e.target.data.label);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help... I dont get what you mean or how that would work... Can you explain it better. Thanks again!

Comment: I've added more of the surrounding code for clarity, and commented everything to explain what's going on.  Let me know if this is helpful, or if you need me to explain anything else.

Comment: You'll need to import the definition:
import fl.controls.listClasses.CellRenderer;

Also, you'll need to import the following:
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;
import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;